# Using ECMP for switching in Layer 2

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, load-balancing, ecmp

`Equal-cost multi-path (ECMP)` is a routing strategy that gives several benefits such as load balancing (as far as I know it is mostly implemented in routers). Suppose there exists a set of switches, say 100 switches, where we want to apply load balancing among them as much as possible by applying ECMP. Therefore, Can `ECMP` serve for switching in Layer 2 in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two protocols that allow ECMP across L2 networks: Transparent Interconnection of Lots of Links (TRILL) and Shortest-Path Bridging (SPB).

TRILL is implemented by exactly two vendors: Cisco (FabricPath) and Brocade (VCS) however both use proprietary implementations, making them incompatible with each other and the standard.

SPB was favoured by Nortel (now Avaya), but is also supported on Alcatel Omniswitch platforms along various HP models, and a few others.

You can do some more investigation here:

SPB - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1aq

TRILL - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRILL_(computing)